# Image is loading outside the workspace area of CropperJS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cropperjs, image-cropper

Image is loading outside the workspace area of CropperJS. I have given default maxHeight and maxWidth to the workspace div. But still image is going out of parent div.

```
    <div class="edited-image">
        <div class="image-workspace">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNwZ3.png)]

I had tried multile things

1. Given default height, width, maxHeight, maxHeight.
2. Also tried by giving minContainerHeight, minContainerWidth to cropperJS.